# Q: What does OptimizableToArrayCall, a PMD rule, stands for in Java?

Tags: java, performance, jvm, pmd

I recently found out the PMD rules and why a development team needs them.

While I was reading them, I found a rule which I can't really understand it. This rule is named as:

> OptimizableToArrayCall

The official [documentation](https://pmd.github.io/pmd-6.11.0/pmd_rules_java_performance.html#optimizabletoarraycall) is writing as a declaration this:

> Calls to a collection’s toArray(E[]) method should specify a target
>   array of zero size. This allows the JVM to optimize the memory
>   allocation and copying as much as possible.

Though I can not understand it completely. How does this accelerates the performance?

Does anyone know the functionality of this rule?

*P.S.: included code would be also great.

Comment: Seems to be obsolete on current JVMs. See [this github issue](https://github.com/pmd/pmd/pull/775). This is a [in depth analysis](https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/arrays-wisdom-ancients/) of the topic if you are interested in the details.

Comment: The reason I am trying to solve this is for implementing it into my code in the future as a fact. The information and the references that you gave me are perfect but also needs too much time to be spent. Of course, is appreciated but I would like to see this in a simple example (if someone will answer in practice with code sample). Thanks for your time though :)

Comment: @Sebastian actually the rule is right, as per that very same issue / analysis. Using 0-sized arrays is the way to go :P

Comment: The reason is that the toArray call just needs to know the type of the array you want to generate, so a 0 length array is all you need. Otherwise, you are just generating an array with elements that will immediately be thrown away.